# Complex limit gives wrong answer

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I'm evaluating $$\lim_{z\to e^{i \pi/2 n}} \frac{z-e^{i \pi/2 n}}{z^{2 n}+1}$$ with Mathematica 9.0.1:

```
In[139]:= Limit[(z - Exp[(I π)/(2 n)])*1/(1 + z^(2 n)), 
z -> Exp[(I π)/(2 n)]]
Out[139]:= 0
```

Mathematica returns 0, but this is not correct. For example, setting n=4, we get a nonzero result:

```
In[140]:= With[{n = 4},
  Limit[1/(1 + z^(2 n)) (z - Exp[I π/(2 n)]), 
  z -> Exp[I π/(2 n)]]
]
Out[140]:= -(1/8) (-1)^(1/8)
```

What went wrong? Is Mathematica assuming something about the value of $n$?

Comment: This is also consistent with `Residue[1/(1 + z^(2 n)), {z, Exp[(I \[Pi])/(2 n)]}]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like *Mathematica* is not handling the `0/0` limit correctly.

```
expr = (z - Exp[(I π)/(2 n)])*1/(1 + z^(2 n)) ;

Simplify[Limit[Numerator[expr], z -> Exp[(I π)/(2 n)]], 
          Assumptions -> { n ∈ Integers}]
Simplify[Limit[Denominator[expr], z -> Exp[(I π)/(2 n)]], 
          Assumptions -> { n ∈ Integers}]
(* 0 *)
(* 0 *)

Simplify[Limit[D[Numerator[expr], z]/D[Denominator[expr], z], 
          z -> Exp[(I π)/(2 n)]], Assumptions -> { n ∈ Integers}]
(* -(E^(((I π)/(2 n)))/(2 n)) *)

Simplify[-(E^(((I π)/(2 n)))/(2 n)) /. n -> 4]
(* -(1/8) (-1)^(1/8) *)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do it another way, approach the limit by angle:

```
c = Exp[(I π)/(2 n)];
expr = (z - a)/(1 + z^(2 n));
exprInθ = FullSimplify[expr /. z -> c Exp[I θ], n ∈ Integers];
Limit[exprInθ, θ -> 0]
```

$-\frac{e^{i \pi /2n}}{2n}$

Answer (score 4):

Let,
$$
f=\frac{z-e^{i \pi/2 n}}{z^{2 n}+1}
$$
Then, in *Mathematica* code, the following seems to work,

```
Limit[f, z -> Exp[(I Pi)/(2 n)], Assumptions -> n >= 1/2]
```

which gives the result,
$$
-\frac{e^{i \pi/2 n}}{2n}
$$
The problem isn't that Mathematica is handling the $0/0$ limit incorrectly.  It's that Mathematica, without additional information, cannot simplify,
$$
(e^{i \pi/2 n})^{2n}
$$
because for $0<n<1/2$ it does not evaluate to -1 and so in the limit you have $0/a$ where *a* is some number not equal to zero.  Thus you get 0 for the limit.  When $n \geq 1/2$ it does evaluate to -1 and so the limit is now $0/0$ which *Mathematica* can handle (as a limit).  **Example:**  Try $n=1/4$ and see that,
$$
(e^{i \pi/2 n})^{2n}
$$
evaluates to 1.

Comment: Exactly right (and an upvote).